# is it possible 8bytes memory input 4bytes? no loss?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

char* str = "abcdefg";
}
```

when i compiled sizeof(str), is 4 bytes, but abcdefg has 8 bytes,

```
    printf("str >> %s\n", str + 1);
```

this code has crushed, it mean, str has just 4 bytes,

where is abcdefg ?

I think, char* str is pointing abcedfg address. then, abcdefg is exist in memory. does it?  therefore,

char* str use 4bytes + 8bytes in system?

Comment: To get the length of a string always use `strlen`.

Comment: Also, printing `str + 1` will not crash if `str` actually points to the string literal `"abcdefg"`, it should print `"bcdefg"`.

Comment: Finally, be careful when using a `char *` to point to string literals, as they are *read only* and should not be modified (which can happen if you have `char *`), instead use `const char *`.

Comment: There are reasons a _pointer_ is not called "array" (and vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(str)` returns the size of the pointer, which is 4 bytes.

**EDIT**:

In practice, size of pointers depends on your system. For 32-bit, it's 4. For 64-bit, it may be 8.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign string literal to `char` *pointer*, `sizeof` produces the size of the pointer on your system. If you want to know how much memory the string literal occupies, assign it to a `char` *array* instead:

```
char str[] = "abcdefg";
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(str));
```

This produces `8`, as expected ([demo](http://ideone.com/ylh58U)).